# Docker Compose : build with docker --rm --force-rm to avoid storing intermediates

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have low memory so I frequently need to delete containers, which sucks.

This github issue https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11154 is raised by a guy who has the same constraints and is being suggested to use

```
docker --rm --force-rm build
```

Can I do the same with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)? How?

The CLI usage doesn't seem to accept:

```
docker-compose --rm --force-rm build
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much this will buy you. --force-rm is only useful if the build fails and you probably don't test builds with compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone has commented, adding these parameters probably isn't going to accomplish much for you. Compose [already defaults to `rm=True`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/1.4.0/compose/service.py#L707).

What you might want to do instead is run something like https://github.com/yelp/docker-custodian with a very short "max age". That way you'll remove any old container and images soon after they exit.